# How to make 2D Vector in AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, vector

I'm able to do it like this:

```
        var levelVector = new Vector.<Vector.<int>>();
        levelVector[0] = new Vector.<int>();
        levelVector[1] = new Vector.<int>();
        levelVector[2] = new Vector.<int>();


        levelVector[0][0] = 0;
        levelVector[0][1] = 0;
        levelVector[0][2] = 5;
        levelVector[0][3] = 0;
        levelVector[0][4] = 0;
        levelVector[0][5] = 0;
        levelVector[1][0] = 0;
        levelVector[1][1] = 0;
        levelVector[1][2] = 5;
        levelVector[1][3] = 0;
        levelVector[1][4] = 0;
        levelVector[1][5] = 0;
        levelVector[2][0] = 0;
        levelVector[2][1] = 5;
        levelVector[2][2] = 2;
        levelVector[2][3] = 2;
        levelVector[2][4] = 2;
        levelVector[2][5] = 2;
```

but I'd rather have something like this:

```
levelVector = [[0,0,3,2,1],[1,1,2,2,2],[3,2,2,1,2]];
```

which would be even more useful like this:

```
levelVector = [
              [0,0,3,2,1],
              [1,1,2,2,2],
              [3,2,2,1,2]
              ];
```

because now it actually reads like a 2D array, or a grid, which would be very helpful.  I think I can do it like this with arrays, so is there a way with Vectors?  Filling in each value for a large 2 dimensional vector, each with its own line of code is hard to look at or make sense of or write.  Am I missing something or this just a short-fall of vectors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said (and to explain it further, since you seem to be a little confused) you can use the [`Vector` *global function*](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#Vector()) to convert an `Array` to a `Vector`:

```
var level:Vector.<int> = Vector.<int>([
    0, 0, 3, 2, 1,
    1, 1, 2, 2, 2,
    3, 2, 2, 1, 2
]);
```

And you can nest calls to this function to form a 2D vector (which you don't really need -- I recommend you just use a flat vector):

```
var level:Vector.<Vector.<int>> = Vector.<Vector.<int>>([
    Vector.<int>([0, 0, 3, 2, 1]),
    Vector.<int>([1, 1, 2, 2, 2]),
    Vector.<int>([3, 2, 2, 1, 2])
]);
```

Or you can simply use pre-populated vector instantiation as [shown in the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html#Vector()):

```
var level:Vector.<Vector.<int>> = new <Vector.<int>>[
    new <int>[0, 0, 3, 2, 1],
    new <int>[1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    new <int>[3, 2, 2, 1, 2]
];
```

Lastly, you could just write a function to convert a 2D array into a 2D vector:

```
function createLevelVector(level:Array):Vector.<Vector.<int>> {
    var levelVector:Vector.<Vector.<int>> = new Vector.<Vector.<int>>(level.length);
    for (var i:int = 0; i < level.length; i++) {
        levelVector[i] = Vector.<int>(level[i]);
    }
    return levelVector;
}

var level:Vector.<Vector.<int>> = createLevelVector(
    [
        [0, 0, 3, 2, 1],
        [1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 2, 2, 1, 2]
    ]
);
```

Comment: You are correct about the `(3)` I was using.  It didn't cause a compile error (not sure why), but it didn't add anything useful either.  I just tested it without that, and works either way, so Flash must just ignore it even though I'm using strict mode and warning mode.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what I said in my question that made it sound like I'm trying to convert an array to a vector.  I'm just trying to create a 2D vector.  Thanks for taking the time on this.  I'll test each of these out.  Your second code block in your answer is the same as @Vesper 's suggestion.  But this doesn't work.  As I said in my answer, the vector seems to need to be created in one line of code, and then it can be populated.

Comment: As for why I'm doing a 2D Array, its because I wan't to be able to iterate through each sub vector for a depth control function elsewhere.

Comment: Using the `Vector` global function (as other answers have) *is* converting an array to a vector. It is *not* instantiating a vector directly (as my 3rd example does). Of course, the difference is mostly semantic; you end up with the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but you cannot directly convert a 2D array (or array of arrays) into a vector of vectors. But you can do like this:

```
var levelVector:Vector.<Vector.<int>>=Vector.<Vector.<int>>(
    [
        Vector.<int>([0,0,3,2,1]),
        Vector.<int>([1,1,2,2,2]),
        Vector.<int>([3,2,2,1,2])
    ]
);
```

Comment: Ah!! Parentheses!! Thanks! I'll give it a whirl tomorrow.

Comment: This doesn't work when I test it.  I fiddled with your code, though, and got it to work.  I tried editing your answer so that I could accept it as correct, but it got rejected.  Oh well.  Maybe you can edit it.  It needs to have one line for constructing the array, then you can fill it the way you have, which is exactly what I am looking for.  So the first line will be `var levelVector:Vector.<Vector>.<int>> = Vector.<Vector.<int>>(3);` and then the next line can be `levelVector = [ //yada yada just like you said`

Comment: Editing an answer is not the correct way to respond. You either comment, or add your own answer on how did you manage to resolve this problem.